# Appium Request to register with grid was unsuccessful: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http http:80 while starting Selenium Grid Node

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-grid

I'm at my wits end with this. I am trying to connect Appium (command line) through an attached device that is visible with adb devices. The grid is launched with the following conmmand

```
java -jar ../../selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig ./hubconfig.json
```

and spins up as it should with the following:

```
C:\projects\mfa-functional\Selenium Batch Files>java -jar
C:/Selenium/SeleniumGrid/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role hub - 
hubConfig C:/Selenium/SeleniumGrid/BatchFiles/Hub/hubconfig.json
13:40:15.686 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: 
'6fbf3ec767'
13:40:15.687 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
2018-04-25 13:40:16.708:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1540ms to 
org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
13:40:16.725 INFO - Will listen on 4444
2018-04-25 13:40:16.781:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
2018-04-25 13:40:16.816:INFO:osjs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager 
workerName=node0
2018-04-25 13:40:16.816:INFO:osjs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, 
using defaults
2018-04-25 13:40:16.818:INFO:osjs.session:main: Scavenging every 600000ms
2018-04-25 13:40:16.825:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started         
o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2d2e5f00{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2018-04-25 13:40:16.852:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started 
ServerConnector@5b0abc94{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2018-04-25 13:40:16.852:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1686ms
13:40:16.853 INFO - Nodes should register to 
http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register/
13:40:16.853 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
```

with the following config.json

```
{
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"maxSessions": 35,
"port": 4444,
"cleanupCycle": 5000,
"timeout": 300000,
"newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
"servlets": [],
"prioritizer": null,
"capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
"throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
"nodePolling": 180000,
"platform": "WINDOWS"
}
```

I am trying to spin up a node to connect to this hub with the following command

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 --nodeconfig MKs_tablet.json
```

MKs_tablet.json looks as follows

```
{
"capabilities":
  [
    {
      "appiumVersion" : "1.8.0",
      "browserName": "andriod",
      "version":"4.4.2",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "platform":"Android",
      "deviceName" : "KJOVSCGISWSC8HOV"
    }
  ],
  "configuration" : 
  {
      "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
      "maxSession": 2,
      "url":"http://http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",
      "host" : "http://127.0.0.1",
      "port": 4723,
      "register": true,
      "registerCycle": 5000,
      "hubPort": 4444,
      "hubHost": "http://127.0.0.1",
      "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000
  }
}
```

The appium node spins up just fine, but cannot seem to connect to the grid hub. The result is as follows:

```
C:\Selenium\SeleniumGrid\ExternalDeviceConfig\Appium Device Configs>appium - 
a 127.0.0.1 --nodeconfig MKs_tablet.json
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.8.0
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: 127.0.0.1
[Appium]   nodeconfig: MKs_tablet.json
[debug] [Appium] Starting auto register thread for grid. Will try to 
register every 5000 ms.
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
[Appium] Request to register with grid was unsuccessful: Error: getaddrinfo 
ENOTFOUND http http:80
[debug] [Appium] Hub down or not responding: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
http http:80
[Appium] Request to register with grid was unsuccessful: Error: getaddrinfo 
ENOTFOUND http http:80
[debug] [Appium] Hub down or not responding: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
http http:80
[Appium] Request to register with grid was unsuccessful: Error: getaddrinfo 
ENOTFOUND http http:80
[debug] [Appium] Hub down or not responding: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
http http:80
[Appium] Request to register with grid was unsuccessful: Error: getaddrinfo 
ENOTFOUND http http:80
[debug] [Appium] Hub down or not responding: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
http http:80
```

Am I just overlooking something be cause there just doesn't seem to be anything suggested out there. I can find anything wrong with my config files. It looks like it should work

HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
[Appium] Request to register with grid was unsuccessful: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http http:80
[debug] [Appium] Hub down or not responding: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http http:80
```

...implies that the *Appium Client* was unable to register with the *Selenium Grid Hub*

Your main issue is within the **--nodeconfig** for the parameter **url** within **MKs_tablet.json** where the protocol **http** is specified twice.

### Solution

Within **--nodeconfig**, the parameter **url** within **MKs_tablet.json** must be set as :

```
"url":"http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"
```

Comment: And that is that we call in the testing field a nice catch

Well played and THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Done......and thank you again. Just to add to the answer because I swear I had seen that and tried it to no avail, I did do one other thing that may have helped to fix this

I changed all the ip addresses in the config json files to localhost from the physical address (127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 as the case may be). So if anyone else stumbles across this question that might something to check out, as well